# Facebook animation how do they do it?

Tags: facebook

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=189943774416975&set=a.189943724416980.45350.135612266516793&type=3&theater

Here you can see they have uploaded a photo in the album and then, there are some animated gif.

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Wow! I don't know we can add GIF to comment of photo.

Comment: The hole will be fixed shortly, i wouldn't worry about seeing much more of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. Don't worry and, please, don't try to do it. It will be closed soon.

Answer (score 1):

These emotions are called "emoji" and now these emotions has been banned by Facebook thats why you are seeing strange characters instead of theses emotions.